# SimpleDateFormat parse() gives incorrect result

Tags: java

Dfault TimeZone GMT-3.00. 
I am parsing new Date("1900/01/01").toString using the parse method of SimpleDateFormat.

The Result i get is 
Sun Dec 31 23:15:16 UYT 1899 
instead of 
Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 UYT 1900

I can't understand why is the result different.

PS: If i change the TimeZone to GMT +5.30 the result is as expected.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you used? It might help shed some light on the problem

Comment: use this instead http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [UYT timezone changes at timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=163&syear=1900), UYT timezone was UTC-3.44.44 prior to 1920 rather than UTC-3.00, so that your result looks correct.

Comment: hi, can you please post the link?

Comment: Thanks a ton. But,by any chance is there a way we could get the expected results..?

Answer (score 1):

are you using this code?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
    System.out.println(sdf.parse("1900/01/01"));
```

Maybe you got the wrong symbols...

Comment: Date d = new Date("1900/01/01");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"); 
System.out.println(sdf.parse(d.toString));

Comment: That's your problem - the String you gave your SimpleDateFormat is wrong.

Comment: but then it should throw a runtime exception which it is not throwing.
If the string is wrong then it should not parse the date in first place right?

Comment: Date d = new Date("1900/01/01"); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"); System.out.println(sdf.parse(d.toString()));  Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1900/01/01"